# Derivation of $f(X)=tr(X^2)$

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

Represent the derivative of the following scalar functions with respect to X $\in$
$\Bbb R^{D \times D}$

How can I get derivative of $f(X)=tr(X^2)$?

Comment: Hello! May you please edit your question with MathJax and provide the steps and methods you have tried to solve this problem? A guide to MathJax can be found here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: tr($X^2$) = $\sum_{i=1}^D \sum_{j=1}^D x_{ji} x_{ij}$

I don't know how to differentiate it.

Comment: I want to play around with this more, but here are some ideas:. 1. Can you rewrite trace in-terms of operations you know the derivative for? (e.g. d/dx[x * x o I]) 2. Can you use the chain rule? df/dtr*dtr/dx=df/dx

Comment: OP, people downvote and close questions that do not include ideas / effort / context /etc. in the body of the question, so I recommend editing to include these things.

Comment: The gradient of the trace of a polynomial (or any other analytic) function is given by
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\,{\rm Tr}(p(X)) = p'(X)^T$$
where $p'$ is the ordinary (scalar) derivative of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

When differentiating $\mathrm{tr}X^2$ with respect to $x_{k\ell}$, there are two cases:

- $x_{k\ell}$ is an off-diagonal entry of $X$ ($k\ne\ell$). Two terms of the summation $\sum_{i,j}x_{ij}x_{ji}$ have nonzero derivative: $x_{k\ell}x_{\ell k}$ and $x_{\ell k}x_{k\ell}$. Both have derivative $x_{\ell k}$, so $(\partial/\partial x_{k\ell})\mathrm{tr}X^2$ is $2x_{\ell k}$.
- $x_{kk}$ is a diagonal entry of $X$. One term of the summation $\sum_{i,j}x_{ij}x_{ji}$ has nonzero derivative: $x_{kk}x_{kk}$. Its derivative is $2x_{kk}$, so $(\partial/\partial x_{kk})\mathrm{tr}X^2=2x_{kk}$.

As a result, the matrix of partials of $\mathrm{tr}X^2$ is in fact $2X^T$.

---

More generally you can do these kinds of things with Kronecker deltas, defined broadly by

$$ \delta_{ab}=\begin{cases} 1 & a=b \\ 0 & a\ne b\end{cases} $$

The partial derivatives are $\partial x_{ij}/\partial x_{k\ell}=\delta_{(i,j)(k,\ell)}=\delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}$. So we could calculate

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{k\ell}}\mathrm{tr}X^2=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{k\ell}}\sum_{i,j}x_{ij}x_{ji}=\sum_{i,j}\left(\frac{\partial x_{ij}}{\partial x_{k\ell}}x_{ji}+x_{ij}\frac{\partial x_{ji}}{\partial x_{k\ell}}\right) $$

by the product rule, then simplify with deltas to

$$ \left(\sum_{i,j}\delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}x_{ji}\right)+\left(\sum_{i,j}x_{ij}\delta_{jk}\delta_{i\ell}\right). $$

In these sums, the $\delta$s are $0$ except when the indices $(i,j)$ are exactly right. In the first summation, this means when $(i,j)=(k,\ell)$, and in the second summation this means when $(j,i)=(k,\ell)$. So the two sums in question become $x_{\ell k}+x_{\ell k}$, as expected.

This way involved more tedious work, but is more general and may be what you have to do when there are lots of indices in play in other problems.